# Ansible Perform Tasks in localhost on Multiple Hosts

Tags: ansible

I'm planning an Ansible playbook which will query version number of specific .exe file on windows hosts, then generate diff version between the version installed on the Windows hosts and the latest version stored on the Ansible controller Linux machine ("localhost"), and deploy the diff version to the Windows hosts.

My playbook looks something like:

```
- hosts: winClients
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  - name: check exe file version
    win_file_version:
      path: C:\my.exe
    register: exe_file_version
  
  - name: Set client version
    set_fact:
      winClientExeVersion: "{{ exe_file_version.win_file_version.file_version }}"
```

Then, on localhost, I have folder for each version, and I'd like to generate the diff between the latest version and the version on the winClients. The versions are stored on localhost in folders named with the version numbers, e.g. `MyVersions/1.0.0.0/abc.exe, abc.dll, aaa.txt, ...` and `MyVersions/1.0.0.1/abc.exe, abc.dll, aaa.txt, ...` etc. And I have special folder, `MyVersions/LatestVersion/` that always contains the latest version. So I need something like:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  - name: check latest version on server using PEV
    shell: peres -v /home/user/MyVersions/LatestVersion/My.exe | awk '{print $3}'
    register: latest_file_version

  - name: Set server version
    set_fact:
      serverLatestVersion: "{{ latest_file_version.stdout }}"

  - name: If versions differ, generate diff between client and latest versions to temp DiffFolder, then delete empty folders
    shell: rsync -rvcm --compare-dest=../{{hostvars.winClients.winClientExeVersion}} . ../DiffFolder && find ../DiffFolder -depth -type d -empty -delete
    args:
      chdir: /home/user/MyVersions/LatestVersion
    when: serverLatestVersion != hostvars.winClients.winClientExeVersion
```

Then I copy the generated diff to the Windows clients using `win_copy`.

Now, all this works OK when `winClients` represents only one specific client.
My problem is, how to do it for group of clients, i.e. in case when `winClients` represents a group instead of one specific computer? How can I generate diff for each client separately (and each client might have different version installed on it), based on its previously-retrieved version number, when its version number differs from the latest version on server?

The `winClients` upper section will assign version number for each of the clients, the problem is with the `localhost` tasks and their `when` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out to be pretty simple: `with_items` does the trick, and it can be referred later in `when` as well.

Example:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  - name: Notify if versions differ
    debug:
      msg: "client and server versions differ: Server: {{ serverLatestVersion}}, Client: {{ hostvars[item]['winClientExeVersion'] }}"
    with_items: "{{ groups['clients'] }}"
    when: serverLatestVersion != hostvars[item]['winClientExeVersion']
```

This will loop through the clients in `clients` group, and for each client that got a different version than the server, notify in debug.
Similar method can be used for each task (copy, rsync, etc.) that requires to be executed only against relevant client, based on `when` condition.